# Xcode - iOS Memory leak that is driving me crazy I think it's NSNotificationCenter, but hoping fresh eyes can see what I can't

Tags: ios, video, modal-dialog, nstimer, nsnotificationcenter

The code here is a modal view launched from the RootViewController and is to display a video with a thumbnail filmstrip below the movie and then timed instructions bound to the movie.

It all works, but there is a memory leak / lack of release that I just can't see for looking and having spent three days trying to fix it, the time has come to ask for help...

If I disable the NSNotificationCenter by commenting it out (highlighted in the .m) I don't have any issues regarding memory and keep the timed text. But I also don't have any thumbnails. I have tried inserting  `[[NSNotificationCenter alloc] removeObserver:self];` at numerous points to see if that will get rid of it for me. But alas, to no avail.

I have also tried releasing the 'backgroundTimer' but it's not overly impressed when I try to compile and run.

In essence, the first time I load the modal view, there are no issues whatsoever and all seems great - However, if I close it with the `-(IBAction)close:(id)sender;` it seems something isn't releasing as the next time I launch the same page the memory usage increases by about 30% (roughly the amount that is used by the thumbnail generation) and increases by roughly the same amount each time I re-launch the modal view.

Please bare in mind I am a newbie to this and the error is likely to a bloody stupid one to those of you in the know. But in the interest of getting this project done, I'll gladly take any abuse you fancy throwing at me.

Here's the code:

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MPMoviePlayerController.h>
#import "ImageViewWithTime.h"
#import "CommentView.h"

@interface SirloinVideoViewController_iPad : UIViewController {
    UIView *landscapeView;
    UIView *viewForMovie;
    MPMoviePlayerController *player;
    UILabel *onScreenDisplayLabel;
    UIScrollView *myScrollView;
    NSMutableArray *keyframeTimes;
    NSArray *shoutOutTexts;
    NSArray *shoutOutTimes;
    NSTimer *backgroundTimer;
    UIView *instructions;
}

-(IBAction)close:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)textInstructions:(id)sender;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *instructions;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *theTimer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *backgroundTimer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *viewForMovie;
@property (nonatomic, retain) MPMoviePlayerController *player;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *onScreenDisplayLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *myScrollView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *keyframeTimes;

-(NSURL *)movieURL;
- (void) playerThumbnailImageRequestDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification;
- (ImageViewWithTime *)makeThumbnailImageViewFromImage:(UIImage *)image andTimeCode:(NSNumber *)timecode;
- (void)handleTapFrom:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;
@end
```

.m

```
#import "SirloinVideoViewController_iPad.h"
#import "SirloinTextViewController.h"

@implementation SirloinVideoViewController_iPad
@synthesize theTimer, backgroundTimer, viewForMovie, player,
   onScreenDisplayLabel, myScrollView, keyframeTimes, instructions; 

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
    [nibNameOrNil release];
    [nibBundleOrNil release];
}

- (IBAction)close:(id)sender{
    [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [player stop];
    [player release];
    [theTimer invalidate];
    [theTimer release];
    [backgroundTimer invalidate];
    [SirloinVideoViewController_iPad release];
}
```

—

```
-(IBAction)textInstructions:(id)sender {

    SirloinTextViewController *vController = [[SirloinTextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:vController animated:YES];
    [vController release];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    keyframeTimes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    shoutOutTexts = [[NSArray 
                      arrayWithObjects:
                      @"1. XXXXXXXXXXXX",
                      @"2. XXXXXXXXXXXX",
                      @"3. XXXXXXXXXXXX",
                      @"4. XXXXXXXXXXXX",
                      @"5. XXXXXXXXXXXX",
                      @"6. XXXXXXXXXXXX"
                      @"7. XXXXXXXXXXXX",
                      @"8. XXXXXXXXXXXX",                     
                      @"9. XXXXXXXXXXXX",                    
                      @"10. XXXXXXXXXXXX",                      
                      @"11. XXXXXXXXXXXX",                      
                      @"12. XXXXXXXXXXXX",                      
                      @"13. XXXXXXXXXXXX",
                      @"14. XXXXXXXXXXXX",                     
                      @"15. XXXXXXXXXXXX",
                      nil] retain];

    shoutOutTimes = [[NSArray 
                      arrayWithObjects:
                      [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt: 1], 
                      [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt: 73],
                      [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt: 109],
                      [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt: 131],
                      [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt: 205],
                      [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt: 250],
                      [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt: 337],
                      [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt: 378],
                      [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt: 402],
                      [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt: 420],
                      [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt: 448],
                      [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt: 507],
                      [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt: 531],
                      [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt: 574],
                      nil] retain];

    self.player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
    self.player.contentURL = [self movieURL];

    self.player.view.frame = self.viewForMovie.bounds;
    self.player.view.autoresizingMask = 
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    [self.viewForMovie addSubview:player.view];

    backgroundTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5f target:self selector:@selector(timerAction:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    [self.view addSubview:self.myScrollView];

    //I am pretty sure that this is the culprit - Just not sure why...

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(movieDurationAvailable:)
     name:MPMovieDurationAvailableNotification
     object:theTimer];

    //Could be wrong, but when commented out I don't have the memory issues
}
```

—

```
- (NSInteger)positionFromPlaybackTime:(NSTimeInterval)playbackTime
{
    NSInteger position = 0;
    for (NSNumber *startsAt in shoutOutTimes)
    {
        if (playbackTime > [startsAt floatValue])
        {
            ++position;
        }
    }
    return position;
}

-(NSURL *)movieURL
{
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *moviePath = 
    [bundle 
     pathForResource:@"sirloin" 
     ofType:@"m4v"];

    if (moviePath) {
        return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}

NSTimeInterval lastCheckAt = 0.0;
```

---

```
- (void)timerAction: theTimer 
{
    int count = [shoutOutTimes count];

    NSInteger position = [self positionFromPlaybackTime:self.player.currentPlaybackTime];

   NSLog(@"position is at %d", position);
    if (position > 0)
    {
        --position;
    }
    if (position < count) 
    {
        NSNumber *timeObj = [shoutOutTimes objectAtIndex:position];
        int time = [timeObj intValue];

        NSLog(@"shout scheduled for %d", time);
        NSLog(@"last check was at %g", lastCheckAt);
        NSLog(@"current playback time is %g", self.player.currentPlaybackTime);

        if (lastCheckAt < time && self.player.currentPlaybackTime >= time)
        {
            NSString *shoutString = [shoutOutTexts objectAtIndex:position];

            NSLog(@"shouting: %@", shoutString);

            CommentView *cview = [[CommentView alloc] initWithText:shoutString];
            [self.instructions addSubview:cview];
            [shoutString release];
        }
    }
    lastCheckAt = self.player.currentPlaybackTime;
}
```

---

```
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}

-(void)removeObserver:(NSObject *)observer forKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:MPMovieDurationAvailableNotification];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageRequestDidFinishNotification];
    [keyPath release];
}

- (void) movieDurationAvailable:(NSNotification*)notification {
    float duration = [self.player duration];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
     addObserver:self 
     selector:@selector(playerThumbnailImageRequestDidFinish:)
     name:MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageRequestDidFinishNotification
     object:nil];

    NSMutableArray *times = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        float playbackTime = i * duration/20;
        [times addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:playbackTime]];
    }
    [self.player 
     requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes:times 
     timeOption: MPMovieTimeOptionExact];
}
```

---

```
- (void) playerThumbnailImageRequestDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
    NSNumber *timecode = 
    [userInfo objectForKey: MPMoviePlayerThumbnailTimeKey]; 
    UIImage *image = 
    [userInfo objectForKey: MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageKey];
    ImageViewWithTime *imageView = 
    [self makeThumbnailImageViewFromImage:image andTimeCode:timecode];

    [myScrollView addSubview:imageView];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = 
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
     initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapFrom:)];
    [tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];

    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

    [tapRecognizer release];
    [image release];
    [imageView release];
}

- (void)handleTapFrom:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    ImageViewWithTime *imageView = (ImageViewWithTime *) recognizer.view;
    self.player.currentPlaybackTime = [imageView.time floatValue];
}
```

---

```
- (ImageViewWithTime *)makeThumbnailImageViewFromImage:(UIImage *)image andTimeCode:(NSNumber *)timecode {
    float timeslice = self.player.duration / 3.0;
    int pos = [timecode intValue] / (int)timeslice;

    float width = 75 * 
    ((float)image.size.width / (float)image.size.height);

    self.myScrollView.contentSize = 
    CGSizeMake((width + 2) * 13, 75);

    ImageViewWithTime *imageView = 
    [[ImageViewWithTime alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(pos * width + 2, 0, width, 75.0f)];

    imageView.time = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:(pos * timeslice)];
    return imageView;

    [myScrollView release];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [player release];
    [viewForMovie release];
    [onScreenDisplayLabel release];
    [keyframeTimes release];
    [instructions release];
    [shoutOutTexts release];
    [shoutOutTimes release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

This app is already out there heavily using UIWebView (which just plain sux) so I am trying to things right and do it properly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do have a couple more issues than **one** leak.

#### The first one

is in your `initWithNibName:bundle:` as you aren't doing anything useful there: get rid of it, entirely! (Besides: don't release arguments, that are passed to your methods! Luckily, you've placed those releases in lines that are unreachable, i.e. after the return statement...)

#### Next method, next problems

1. Why are you sending `release` to a class object? Don't! That's wrong on *many* levels.
2. You have decided to create properties for your timers. That's nothing bad per se. But why then, are you using the ivars directly here? I'd strongly encourage you to implement `setTheTimer:` and `setBackgroundTimer:` to handle the invalidation and release properly and simply do `self.theTimer = nil; self.backgroundTimer = nil;` here. That would fix the asymmetry in handling those things, as well. (By the way: theTimer isn't *such* a great name for an ivar...especially when there is **another** ivar that is a timer!)

`textInstructions:` looks unsuspicious but...

#### `viewDidLoad` has some more issues

1. It leaks an MPMoviePlayerController:
   The `@property` will retain it, so you need to balance the `alloc` here.
2. `backgroundTimer` has a corresponding `@property` that is declared to be retaining: You are violating this API contract here, since you only assign the timer to the ivar. Use `self.backgroundTimer = ...` instead.
3. From all the code you posted, it seems to me that passing `theTimer` as the last argument in your call to `-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]` is a fancy way of passing in `nil` as that parameter. Which is kind of good, because usually `NSTimer` doesn't post too many `MPMovieDurationAvailableNotification`s. In fact, as I can't see `theTimer` being used except in `close:`: Could it be that this is just a useless remnant from before you introduced the `backgroundTimer` ivar/@property? (Well there is another occurrence of a variable of that name, but it should be accompanied by a big fat compiler warning...)
4. Do you, in any way, implement `viewDidUnload`? If so, does it:

   1. `self.player = nil;`?
   2. `[shoutOutTexts release], shoutOutTexts = nil;`?
   3. `[shoutOutTimes release], shoutOutTimes = nil;`?
   4. `self.keyframeTimes = nil;`?
   5. `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name: MPMovieDurationAvailableNotification object:nil];`?
   6. `self.backgroundTimer = nil;`? (Assuming, `setBackgroundTimer:` releases **and invalidates** the old value)
5. **Update** I've missed this one on the first go: You are leaking 15 `NSNumber`s here. Use `[NSNumber numberWithInt:]` instead of alloc/init in the setup of `shoutOutTimes`.

A minor remark on `movieURL`, which you can turn into the following one-liner:

```
-(NSURL*)movieURL {
    return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"sirloin" withExtension:@"m4v"];
}
```

#### And then this

`NSTimeInterval lastCheckAt = 0.0;` within the global scope. From your usage of it: ivar PLZ?!?one?

More issues later. I gotta get myself something to eat first.

---

### Part Two

#### Now let's get into `timerAction:`

The first issue is not too grave, — especially in this particular context — but you should be aware that `-[NSArray count]` returns an `NSUInteger` and that the *U* is not a typo, but a designation that this value is unsigned. You certainly won't run into problems with the signedness in this App and rarely do on other occasions, but *when* you do, they make up for really funky bugs and you should be aware of the implications...
The real issue with this method is, however, that you are **leaking one `CommentView` per iteration** while — at the same time — **overreleasing one `NSString`.** The fact, that you were using string literals (which will never be dealloced) in the first place, (i.e. when you were initializing shoutOutTimes) totally saves your butt, here.

#### Next up: `removeObserver:forKeyPath:`

You **really** should get rid of that really bad habit of releasing parameters, that are passed to your methods!

That being said, get rid of the entirety of this method!

First and foremost `removeObserver:forKeyPath:` is a method from the `NSKeyValueObserving` informal protocol and plays a totally different role than what you are (ab-)using it to accomplish here. 
Secondly, it is one of those methods where it is essential to call through to `super` if — by any means — you *really* need to override it. (Well, except, when you were overriding `addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:` as well and-it-should-go-without-saying-that-you-shouldn't-do-that-unless-you-really-know-what-you-are-doing-if-you-ever-planned-on-using-KVO.)

#### `movieDurationAvailable:`

Like Evan said, you're leaking `times` here. Go for his suggestion or — instead — make it `NSMutableArray *times = [NSMutableArray array];` and you are done here.

#### `playerThumbnailImageRequestDidFinish:`

You don't own `image`, so don't release it!
Personally, I would finish setting up the view (i.e. add the recognizer and do stuff like that) before adding it into the view-hierarchy, but that's  completely a matter of taste...

#### `makeThumbnailImageViewFromImage:andTimeCode:`

...leaks an `NSNumber` (use `[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(pos * timeslice)]` instead of  the `alloc/initWithFloat:`-dance) and prevents you from crashing due to overreleasing `myScrollView` by the unconditional return statement that directly precedes it (phew!).
While we're at it: rename this method to either `newThumbnailImageView...` so that when you'll revisit this code in a year or so, you instantly know that `[imageView release];` at the bottom of `playerThumbnailImageRequestDidFinish:` really is necessary, without having to look at the implementation of this method.
Alternatively, you could rename it to `thumbnailImageView...` and change the return statement to `return [imageView autorelease];`. Bonus: one fewer line in `playerThumbnailImageRequestDidFinish:` as the `[imageView release];` there becomes obsolete then.

#### `dealloc`

Add `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];` at the very top.

The rest of it looks okay. (Although I find it odd, that the ivar `landscapeView` is never/nowhere mentioned apart from its declaration.)

#### Summary

Read the sections *[Memory Management Rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html)* and *[Autorelease](https://web.archive.org/web/20110309224051/http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-SW5)* from Apple's "Memory Management Programming Guide" once again. They're pure gold!

Comment: You're a star! - Slowly working through the list - I must admit, a lot of the crap in there was an attempt to see where the main issue may be. And yes, theTimer was indeed the starting point and there are no compiler warnings, which is why I have been pretty confused. Thanks for your time - it is seriously appreciated!

Comment: Finished it. Like I said: Happy Birthday! Besides: You wouldn't want to have a look at some of the code I produced just one or even two years ago...

Comment: @danyowdee, I wish I could give you +2 for such a detail response.

Comment: That is all seriously beyond the call of duty!!! A massive thank you... It's going to take me a while to digest, but I seriously cannot express my appreciation enough. Can't click the up arrows just yet as not quite the points - That will be very much rectified when I do!

Comment: ivar Landscape was for something after I fixed the probs as they didn't seem to be probs until I ran it on the iPad....

Comment: @danyowdee: +1 for a very detailed response. Much more in-depth than mine.

Comment: @Stewart I've somehow managed to not see yet another memory leak in viewDidLoad. Updated my answer accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

You never release `times` in `movieDurationAvailable:`:

```
NSMutableArray *times = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

You should use `autorelease` when you pass it to the method:

```
[self.player requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes:[times autorelease] timeOption: MPMovieTimeOptionExact];
```

Comment: An alternative is to explicitly release it as well. After `requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes::`, call `[times release];`. Either way will work.

Comment: @Ryan: Correct. There are usually many ways to handle memory management. Most of the time it boils down to user-preference.

Comment: I take it `autorelease` is your preferred method in cases like this? I can't say I blame you. I may end up adopting this instead of my suggestion from here on out. It just feels....cleaner. I just figured I would contribute alternatives is all, absolutely nothing wrong with your answer. Next time I'll also @OP, since it was meant as a contribution, and not any form of a correction/question.

Comment: @Ryan: I did take your comment as a contribution. I always appreciate the input of others. I do agree that my method feels cleaner; I like to perform the cleanup as soon as I can.

Comment: My understanding of `autorelease` means it is released after the stack unwinds fully, which would be later than the `release` method. Then again, the code feels cleaner with `autorelease` and it isn't released *that* much later.

Comment: Thanks all... I'll have a look tomorrow - I've had a couple too many B'day drinks thinks this evening - But seriously appreciate your time!

Comment: @Ryan Wersal you are right in that `autorelease` delays the release of the object, although you're wrong in that this hasn't much to do with "the" stack: `autorelease` simply adds the object to the top-most element of _a_ stack formed by `NSAutoreleasePool` instances. When this element get's popped of said stack, (typically by being sent a `drain` message) it releases all the objects that were added to it. If you didn't create a local `NSAutoreleasePool`, that will probably be the pool that is created at the beginning and drained at the end of any iteration of the current runloop.

Comment: @danyowdee The idea of "the stack unwinding" came from the Stanford iOS videos I watched recently. I am guessing that is because the `drain` message is not sent in the current "stack" of methods in the current event handling pipe.